# What is a full conditional probability?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I know what is a conditional probability distribution. But what is exactly *full conditional probability*?

Comment: You're just going to get an answer stating the definition of conditional probability (or linking here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) but I don't think that's what you're looking for. Can you explain exactly what your question is?

Comment: It would help to put the term in context say by quoting the sentence where you saw it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the context is a MCMC algorithm, because this terminology is rather standard in such a context. The goal is to simulate a multivariate distribution, that is, the distribution of a random vector $(\theta_1, \ldots,\theta_p)$. The full conditional distribution of $\theta_1$ is then nothing but the conditional distribution of $\theta_1$ given all other variables.

Comment: could you please explain how "conditional" differs from "marginal"?

Comment: @Abe "marginal" is precisely "unconditional" :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the probability distribution of a variable (node) in probabilistic graphical model (PGM) conditioned on the value of all the other variables in the PGM. It is equal to the distribution of the variable conditioned on the values of its Markov blanket which is formed by the children, the parents and coparents of the node.

As suggested by [Stephane](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/8402/st%C3%A9phane-laurent)  this is useful for MCMC sampling.